# "objects" lists variables, x for example, but "summary (x)" yields "object x not found"

Tags: r

"objects" provides a list of variables:

```r
[1] "alter"    "bogen"    "chancen"  "deutsch"  "englisch"
[6] "geschl"   "iq"       "klasse"   "mathe"    "schultyp"
```

but:

```r
summary(alter)
Error in summary(alter) : object 'alter' not found
```

Comment: If `objects` is just a vector of strings, `"alter"` is only a string, not a variable. It does not seem to be in `ls()`

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to write `objects()` instead of `objects` (and most R users instead use its synonym, `ls()`, so you should be aware that this function exists, too).

Calling the function `objects()` (or `ls()`) will show you that no object of name `alter` exists in your environment. By contrast, it will show that a name *`objects`* exists (that is, a variable with the same name as the function), which is a character vector containing the strings character strings `"alter"`, `"bogen"`, etc.